# solve: $[0\leq A\leq 360°]$

Tags: trigonometry

solve:

$\sqrt {3}\cot A.\cot 2A-\cot A-\cot 2A=\sqrt {3}$

My Attempt:
$$\sqrt {3}\cot A.\cot 2A-\cot A-\cot 2A-\sqrt {3}=0$$
$$\sqrt {3}(\cot A.\cot 2A-1)-1(\cot A+\cot 2A)=0$$

Why did I not get common factors here. Please suggest what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sqrt {3}(\cot A\cdot\cot 2A-1)-1(\cot A+\cot 2A)=0$$
$$\implies \sqrt {3}(\cot A\cdot\cot 2A-1)=(\cot A+\cot 2A)$$
$$\implies \sqrt {3}=\frac{\cot A+\cot 2A}{\cot A\cdot\cot 2A-1}$$
$$\implies \sqrt {3}=\frac{\tan 2A+\tan A}{1-\tan A\cdot\tan 2A}=\tan(2A+A)=\tan 3A$$
$$\implies \tan 3A=\sqrt3=\tan \frac{\pi}{3}$$ $$\implies 3A=n\pi+\frac{\pi}{3}$$

So $\color{red}{A=\frac{n\pi}{3}+\frac{\pi}{9}}$ where $n=0,1,2, \ldots$

Now choose $n$ such that $0^\circ<A<360^\circ$ according to your question.

Comment: How do I make use of $A=n\pi+\frac {\pi}{3}$? Please suggest. I am not familiar with this.

Comment: @user354073 You just need to choose proper values of $n$ and check if $A$ lies in that interval. Trial and error, just.

Comment: I guess your formula for $Tan(A-B)$ is mistake? Please check it once.

Comment: @user354073 Yes you are right. It will be $\tan(A+B)$.